# How to find duplicate values in a list and modify them?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that might contains duplicated values, I want to find them and add some letters or numbers to them, but leave the other values alone.
For example:
`input_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'E']`
Expected output:
`output_list = ['A1', 'B', 'C', 'A2', 'D1', 'D2', 'A3', 'E']`
Is it possible to do this?
**Edit:**
Someone asked me to show the actual code, so I will put them here.
I'm really new to programming just about 2 weeks, so I'm sorry if I did anything stupid.
I was actually making a RPG as one of my exam in *LPTHW*, I have some classes of monsters, and instantiate them into a list.
They appears randomly and might be duplicated.
So if there are duplicated monsters, I need to add a letter in the end of their names to differentiate them.
For example like "Goblin A" and "Goblin B".

```
class Goblin(Monsters):

    name = "Goblin"
    hp = 10
    blah...

# and other classes of the monsters

Goblin = Goblin()
Orc = Orc()
Giant = Giant()
Dragon = Dragon()

monsters = [Goblin, Orc, Giant, Dragon]
```

They appears randomly, for example there are 2 duplicates:

```
monster_party = []
choose_monster = random.sample(self.monsters, 2)
four_two_copy1 = copy.deepcopy(choose_monster)
four_two_copy2 = copy.deepcopy(choose_monster)
monster_party.extend(four_two_copy1 + four_two_copy2)
```

I write a function but it will apply on every objects:

```
def add_letter(input_list):
    letters = []
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        letter = chr(ord('A') + i)
        letters.append(letter)
        i += 1
    for obj, letter in zip(input_list, letters):
        obj.name += ' ' + letter
    return input_list
```

The output example:

```
Goblin A
Orc B
Giant C
Dragon D
```

Thanks for all the kind answers, I really appreciate it. I'll test all of them and accept with cautious.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @dejdej Thanks for the comment. I tried make a function that add increasing number or letters to the end of the values, but that function will handle every values in a whole list, instead of just the duplicate ones. I'm new to Python only about 2 weeks, I can't figure out other way to do this.

Comment: Please show the actual code you tried, the result you got from it, and highlight how that is different from the result you want.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the comment, I put my code examples in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some simple utils:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import count

c = Counter(input_list)

iters = {k: count(1) for k, v in c.items() if v > 1}
output_list = [x+str(next(iters[x])) if x in iters else x for x in input_list]
# ['A1', 'B', 'C', 'A2', 'D1', 'D2', 'A3', 'E']
```

You will need two iterations either way. First, to collect the ones that occur more than once. Second, to augment those elements with their incrementing count.

Comment: This is the fast by using the optimized python lib. module.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution comes to my mind like the following,

```
from collections import Counter
input_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'E']
count = Counter(input_list)
copy_of_count = count.copy() # So, that we can decrease count of elementes from it
output_list = []

for char in input_list:
    if count[char]>1:
        suffix = str(count[char]-copy_of_count[char]+1) # append a suffix
        copy_of_count[char] -= 1
    else:
        suffix = '' # if repeated once, no need for a suffix
    output_list.append(char+suffix)

print(output_list)
```

Output

```
['A1', 'B', 'C', 'A2', 'D1', 'D2', 'A3', 'E']
```

Kindly accept and upvote if it was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

A way I can think of:

In the first traverse, tease out those chars occurs more than once firstly.

In the second traverse, keep how many times you have met a char, and modified it.

```py
# traverse 1
freq = {}
for c in input_list:
    if c in freq:
        freq[c] += 1
    else:
        freq[c] = 0

# those chars more than one time
target_chars = set(c for c, f in freq.items() if f > 1)

# traverse 2
output_list = []
met = {}
for c in input_list:
    if c in target_chars:
        if c not in met:
            met[c] = 0
        met[c] += 1
        output_list.append(c + str(met[c]))
    else:
        output_list.append(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few ways, though I'll mention a simple one since you're starting your journey on python.

You can traverse the list and update the duplicates

```
# We'll use this to keep track of the increments that we are doing to each duplicate
counter_map = {}
for index, value in enumerate(input_list):
    # If the current element is present in the rest of the array i.e. `index + 1 to n`
    if value in input_list[index + 1:]:
        # If the counter_map has this variable initialised already, increment and use that value, else initialise to 1
        if counter_map.get(value):
            counter_map[value] = counter_map[value] + 1
        else:
            counter_map[value] = 1
        input_list[index] = "%s%s" % (value, counter_map[value])
print(input_list)
```